# More Pythonic / elegant way to fill a 2D array with sequences of integers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, range

I want to create a 6x6 numpy matrix, with the first row filled with: `0, 1, ..., 5`, the second row filled with `10, 11, ... , 15`, and the last row filled with `50, 51, ... , 55`.

I thought about using *(1)* nested (two layer) list comprehensions, and then converting list-of-list into a `numpy.matrix` object, or *(2)* using variables inside of `range` function, i.e. - `range(x)` and vary `x` from 1 to 6.  I was not able to get either of these two ideas to work.

Below is my non-vectorized / looping code to construct this matrix.  Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this?

```
a = np.zeros((6,6))
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        a[i,j] = 10*i + j
print(a)
```

(This is one of the examples given at 39:00 in the intro video to `NumPy` on Youtube:
[Intro to Numerical Computing with NumPy](https://youtu.be/V0D2mhVt7NE?t=2341)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html#numpy.ogrid)?

```
np.add(*np.ogrid[:60:10, :6]) 

# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
#        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
#        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
#        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

**Details**
`ogrid` returns an open meshgrid:

```
a, b = np.ogrid[:60:10, :6]
a

# array([[ 0],
#        [10],
#        [20],
#        [30],
#        [40],
#        [50]])

b
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

You can then perform broadcasted addition:

```
# a + b
np.add(a, b)

# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
#        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
#        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
#        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

---

Similarly, you can also generate two ranges using `np.arange` and add them:

```
np.arange(0, 60, 10)[:,None] + np.arange(6)

# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
#        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
#        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
#        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished with broadcasting,

```
arange(0, 6) + 10*arange(0, 6)[:, None]

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
   [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
   [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
   [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
   [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

I'd recommend reading https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html.  "Pythonic" doesn't really matter when working with numpy.  Some times iterating, list comprehensions, and other pythonic approaches work well with arrays, other times they are terribly inefficient.  However, the links given cover some high level concepts that are very powerfull with numpy.

Comment: Fascinating solution.  Thanks so much!